# Secure REST endpoints with service user or public user

Tags: java, rest, web-services, security, spring-boot

I'm writing a mobile app that communicates to a remote Java service via REST.  I have protected my (SpringBoot) web service with https protection (due to the nature of the data, it needs to be secure) but my question is about which user/password I use to secure the https calls.

Should the username and password I use in the https header be a service account that the client (mobile app) and Java service knows or should it be the public user's username and password?  The easiest option is just to use a service account but this means the mobile app will have those details built into it and distributed publically (albeit in compiled form).

Going the other way and using the user's username and password means I'll have to have the logon REST endpoint open and unsecure (which is fine I guess), but it just makes it slightly more fiddly.

Answer (score 0):

Good question, and I would reckon you to use token based authentication and authorization scheme. Firstly you should have a login page where client logs in by providing username and password which is authenticated by calling some remote login service which maintains it's own user store or may use an existing one in your organization if any. Upon a successful authentication, the auth service should provide the client with a valid token, which then be refreshed time to time. The mobile or web client should pass in the token to the downstream microservices when a request is sent and this token should be sent inside the `Authorization` HTTP header.

Exposing the username and password while passing it around the network normally not considered as a good solution and that's where token becomes handy too. Token is the normal procedure that people use to secure rest endpoints. Yous rest endpoint should intercept each and every request comes at it, passes the token to the auth provider and verifies that. If the token is valid it will allow the request otherwise it should deny it.

Security is a pretty much larger topic and you have X.509 certificates other than tokens to encrypt the data sent across the wire over `https` and so forth. I suggest you to take a look at the spring security [documentation](https://docs.spring.io/spring-security/site/docs/current/reference/htmlsingle/) since that will be a good starting point. Spring Security gives lots of hooks for developers which can be used out of the box with some sensible defaults. You can use JWT style tokens, Oauth tokens and spring security supports all these different forms too.

Comment: Thanks for the response.  What I'm really trying to understand is when in the conversation the service becomes fully encrypted.